# Returning incorrect $post->ID after installing plugin

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I've experimented installing a plugin called Sell Media https://graphpaperpress.com/extensions/sell-media/ and I seem to be getting a conflict with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

After installing I've noticed that some ACF fields I require for my homepage now do not work. Even after disabling the plugin I am experiencing this problem.

I've discovered that the issue is because the wrong $post->ID is now being returned. When I print out to the screen the ID returned is 94939291908928262420 when in fact I can see the ID for that page is actually 6 in the database.

Below is the code I am using which has been working fine up to now. Can anyone help with me with what the issue may be?

Thanks in advance

```
global $post;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page'
) );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();

        $post_id            = $post->ID;
        $cta_story_text     = get_field('story_cta_text', $post_id);
        $cta_story_link     = get_field('story_cta_link', $post_id);
        $cta_story_label    = get_field('story_cta_label', $post_id);
    endwhile;
```

Comment: It sounds like `wp_reset_query()` or `wp_reset_postdata()` needs to be called in the conditional but before the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Howdy_McGee but neither of those have seemed to work.

Comment: So if you print the post object, via `print_r( $post )` - what page does it show? Could it be that it's trying to pull autosaves or non-published types? If the two functions suggested above did not work then it leads me to believe the issue lies with the query, either $args provided to WP_Query or possible a `pre_get_posts` or similar hook modifying the query before it gets called.